# What does this regex mean?: (?s

Tags: regex

What does this mean in regex?

```
(?s:.+?)
```

specifically

```
(?s
```

I've seen things like non capture groups `(?:regex)`, lookaheads but this is the first time I see something like this, I got it from the MarkDownExtra parser definition lists part.

I was unable to find it on http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and Google because you can't physically google question marks, so I am asking here.

Also isn't `.+?` the same as `.*`?

Comment: `.+` matches between 1 and unlimited times, `.*` matches between 0 and unlimited times.

Comment: http://regex101.com/ is another pretty good site for testing/explaining regexes. You have answers already, but for the record it says ("match the remainder of the group with the following options: s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters").

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: @aliteralmind Thank you, I don't know how I missed that, I guess I just didn't imagine it being a modifier at all.

Comment: `.+` one or more greedy, `.+?` one or more lazy, didn't know this.

Comment: Consider [RegexBuddy](http://regexbuddy.com) if you're on Windows. It's a great application for analyzing regexes. For constructing regexes, they also have [RegexMagic](http://www.regexmagic.com/), which I've not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an inline modifier:

```
(?s)
```

That was extended so that only the part within the group is affected. This means that the `.` within the group will be on 'dotall' mode (or match newlines too).

Answer (score 2):

Using [this link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) You can get explanation of your regex.

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?s)                     set flags for this block (with . matching
                           \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $
                           matching normally) (matching whitespace
                           and # normally)
```

Comment: You can use [this link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl). Its made based on Perl's `YAPE::Regex::Explain` module.

Comment: @SabujHassan thank you for the link, it makes things much clearer than the much prettier regex101 website